# how can i get back to previous line of code in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

```
1)declare 
2)vrec emp%rowtype;
3)begin
4)select * into
5)vrec from emp
```

How can I move the cursor back to `declare` section (line 2) in sqlplus command window?

Comment: You can't. Write you PL/SQL block in a text editor and paste it into SQLplus instead. Or even better: Use a tool like SQL Developer, TOAD, PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: we have a new command line interface, SQLcl, which allows you to use the arrow keys to navigate your commands/scripts as you type them..and do much more http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't "move the cursor" but you can "bring back" line 2.

`list 2` or `l 2` (you do need to know which line you need to go back to - however, in a short command like that, only five lines, you can try `l 2` and if it's the wrong line then you can try `l 3` etc.)

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve028.htm#SQPUG049

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your favourite editor. For example, if you want to use vi, then

```
define _EDITOR=vi
```

You can then type "edit" and edit the current statement in vi